# MYSQL Hibernate 5.2 createStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures

Here is my code to call a mysql stored procedure

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = getCurrentSession().createStoredProcedureQuery("updateinselgibilitycount")
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("ppatientinsid", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("pencounterID", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .setParameter("ppatientinsid", ppatientinsid).setParameter("pencounterID", encounterID);
    query.execute();
```

And i am getting the following error

```
    10:04:42.167 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] WARN  o.h.p.internal.ProcedureCallImpl - HHH000456: Named parameters are used for a callable statement, but database metadata indicates named parameters are not supported.
Hibernate: 
    {call updateinselgibilitycount(?,?)}
10:04:42.329 [http-nio-8080-exec-3] ERROR c.p.w.utilities.ExceptionHandler - User ID : 1 
Error : org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:413)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateExceptionTranslator.java:54)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an transaction to execute the stored procedure. Annotate your method with `@Transactional`

Answer (score 0):

It's related to the correction of [HHH-8740](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-8740) :

> In some cases, the database metadata is incorrect (i.e., says something is not >supported, when it actually is supported). In this case it would be preferable to simply log a warning. If it turns out that named parameters really are not supported, then a SQLException will be thrown later when the named parameter is bound to the SQL statement.

So, the warning warn you from calling a method that queries metadata on named parameters.

Just simple disable warning in hibernate logging so it will not issue on console.
set below property in your application.properties

```
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR
```